# Send ether to contract address in web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, crowdsale, fallback-function

I want to send ether to this contract's contribute function using web3.js

I'm trying below code for the same but this doesn't work for me.

```
var AbiOfContract = 'abi_code';
var contractAddress = "0x8bbc*************************";
var contract1 = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(AbiOfContract)).at(contractAddress);

contract1.contribute({"to": contractAddress ,"from": accounts[1], "value": web3.toWei("10.0", "ether")},"password");
```

```
contract CrowdFunder {

    function contribute()
    public
    inState(State.Fundraising) payable returns (uint256)
    {
        contributions.push(
            Contribution({
                amount: msg.value,
                contributor: msg.sender
                })
            );
        totalRaised += msg.value;
        currentBalance = totalRaised;
        LogFundingReceived(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised);
        checkIfFundingCompleteOrExpired();
        return contributions.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should not have included "password" at the end of contribute call. To unlock your wallet you have to execute in geth [personal.unlockAccount](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_unlockaccount).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to accept the Ether in a smart contract then you should have a fallback function. The fallback function will be called by default when someone transfers ETH to the contract address.

```
contract Crowdfunder{
   function() Crowdfunder { }
   function() payable {
      contributions.push(
        Contribution({
            amount: msg.value,
            contributor: msg.sender
            })
        );
    totalRaised += msg.value;
    currentBalance = totalRaised;
    LogFundingReceived(msg.sender, msg.value, totalRaised);
    checkIfFundingCompleteOrExpired();
  }
}
```

In web3js you can send through the normal transaction.

```
let send = web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase,to:contract_address, value:web3.toWei(0.05, "ether")});
```

For further reference regarding fallback function [check here.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function)

Comment: I have used fallback function but it is not working.

Comment: A fallback function is not required, any function with payable modifier should be able to accept ether.

Comment: If you are sending ETH to a particular function in the smart contract then payable function is enough for that, but if you want to send ETH to a contract address like to a wallet address then fallback function with the payable modifier is required. [For reference](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17465/how-can-a-smart-contract-run-when-receiving-ether-directly-not-through-a-functi)

Comment: If I want to send ETH to a particular function with payable modifier then how I can call that function in web3.js sendTransaction function??

Comment: Mycontract.methods.Mymethod(params).send(from:"address", to:"contractaddress", value:"in wei");   it will do your needs

Comment: If anyone else want to send ether into my contract using my contract address??

Comment: If anyone wants to send Ether to your contract address then you need to have fallback function with a payable modifier.  In web3 you can achieve that by Mycontract.methods.send(from:"address", to:"contractaddr", to:"value");  When they send Ether to your contract addr by default fallback function will get triggered.

Comment: I had make fallback function and use web3.js sendTransaction function to send ether in contract, transaction successfully committed but the fallback function didn't called automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67563/discussion-between-rahul-sati-and-karthikeyan-thangavel).

Comment: Thanks. That solved my confusion about sending ether. I was sending the from and to accounts to the contract itself. Now I understand you have to send money to a contract just like to send money to another account. Then the the contract does some with that money you gave to it. Thanks

Comment: It is now `web3.utils.toWei`

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, funding a contract is best done with the [**receive**](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.2/contracts.html?#receive-ether-function) function.

```
contract CrowdFunder {
  receive () external payable {
    // what to do when receiving funds...
  }
}
```

You can then trigger the receive function by sending ether directly to the contract address.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: senderAddress,
  to: contractAddress,
  value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'),
});
```

It was previously possible to do so with the fallback function, which now has a limit of 2300 gas to perform operations (the `receive` function does not have a gas limit).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to write a test suite in Truffle where I initially fund my smart contract in order to operate certain operations.

Inside my Test script, I had something like this:

```
it("Funds the Smart Contract With Test Ether", async () => {
  const addressContract = await TriviaContract.address
  await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: accounts[9],
    to: String(addressContract),
    value: String(await web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether"))
  });
  const ContractBalance = await web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(TriviaContract.address))
  console.log(ContractBalance);
})
```

Whenever I will run my test script, I would get an error that looks like this:

[image]

My transaction was reverting because I did not enable my Smart Contract to receive Ethers. All I had to do was add a special `receive()` function inside my smart contract and everything worked after that:

```
receive () external payable {
    // Do whatever you want when receiving funds...
  }
```

I hope this helps anyone out there who was experiencing the same issue.

Cheers.